# After migrate command, Django automatically creates sqlite3 but doesn't automatically create postgresql database

Tags: python-3.x, django, database, postgresql, sqlite

I'm using Windows 10 and Visual Studio Code IDE with python 3.8.5 . I'm developing a web app called tasksplanner and I want to use django for my backend and postgresql v12 for my database.

By default django comes with sqlite3.

In the file settings.py of my django project (called backend) by default I find this code:

```
DATABASES = {
     'default': {
         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
         'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
     }
}
```

If on the terminal I do:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

or

```
python manage.py makemigrations tasksplanner
```

django automatically creates an sqlite3 database called db.sqlite3 inside the backend project folder

However, I want to use postgresql.

So, following the instructions in [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-postgresql-with-your-django-application-on-ubuntu-16-04) I modified my settings.py to look like:

```
DATABASES = {
    # 'default': {
    #     'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    #     'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    # }

    'default': {

            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',

            'NAME': 'tasks_planner_db.mkd',

            'USER': 'postgres',

            'PASSWORD': '1234',

            'HOST': '127.0.0.1',

            'PORT': '5432',
    }

}
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "tasks-planner-db.mkd" does not exist
```

My questions are:

1. Why isn't django creating the postgresql database automatically like it did with sqlite3? What do I do to make it create the postgresql database automatically? Or do I have to create it manually?
2. Is the extension for the postgresql database correct? Should it be something different than *.mkd
3. I would also like the postgresql database to be created on the same location as the where sqlite3 database is created. How can I achieve this? If I do :

   'NAME': BASE_DIR /'tasks-planner-db.mkd',

I get the error:

```
lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 160, in get_connection_params
    if len(settings_dict['NAME'] or '') > self.ops.max_name_length():
TypeError: object of type 'WindowsPath' has no len()
```

Comment: I would spend some time in the [Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/). Hint: make sure you get to [Part 2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial02/). Also, Sqlite is an embedded(single file) database, Postgres is not. It does not have a file extension. The [Pg Tutorial](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial.html) will help. In other words you have lots of homework to do yet.

Comment: I know. Thank you for pointing me to the right direction. I was able to complete the tutorial on my link using sqlite3 but I wanted to change things a bit using postgre

Comment: And part 2 of the tutorial explains how to do that under the note `For databases other than SQLite`. Once you decide to go that route you will also need to know how set up and manage Postgres, which is why I pointed you at the Postgres link. Sqlite3 is nice for quick and dirty. Postgres is nice for client/server and multi-user use, but it does require more work to manage. So you need to spend some time learning it's needs.

Comment: Following tutorial 2, I have been able to successfully create and connect to the database. I created it using the pgAdmin4 tool. However, I wonder where this tool creates the files for the new database

Comment: Assuming you used the EDB installer and you did not change the defaults they should be under `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12` per information [here](https://www.enterprisedb.com/edb-docs/d/postgresql/installation-getting-started/installation-guide-installers/12/invoking_the_graphical_installer.html).  The only files you need to worry about are postgresql.conf(main config file) and pg_hba.conf(authentication file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django can only create sqlite databases. When you change the database to a postgresql it asks you for your username password and port so it can connect to the existing database, not to create a knew one.

The solution to you problem is to create a postgresql database it can connect to with those details.

Answer (score 0):

Django can create a sqlite database for you because sqlite is purely file based. It can not create a postgres database because it would require a server running it as well.

Therefore, you need to start up a postgres database server, create a user there and then tell django the access details. You can get such a server up and running very quickly by using a docker image: https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres